# How should I calculate "fill rate"? People inquire about an item and then buy it days/months later?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

So I have **posts**(people posting a want for an item) and then I have **fills**(the person actually getting the item)

There are hundreds of posts per day but the fill for that item can be days or weeks away from the post day. Currently the "fill rate" is just how many fills/how many posts happened that day which is not accurate since they two are not related. Is there a better(accurate) way to calculate this fill rate?

Comment: You should probably say what you want from the fill rate, i.e. what are the properties you want to measure.

Comment: Yes, I can think of a number of stats methods, depending on what you actually want to measure.  The average age of all requests filled on a particular date might be a useful number.  Another interesting number might be the "half-life" or requests from a particular day, treating the "posts" as an exponential decay problem.  If you are willing to look at a graph, various histograms might be a clearer way to look at your numbers.  It all depends on what you want to find out.

Comment: We currently measure fill rate as a percentage of posts.  So if we had 100 posts today and 15 fill we had a 15% fill rate.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Please consider posting your comment to an answer, since it's unlikely that a more specific answer can be given here.